# Could not find parent artifact xxxxx:pom:2.0-SNAPSHOT

Tags: java, maven

I have a parent project xxx-third, which has nothing but a pom declaring some dependencies and build configurations.

After I deploy it to the nexus and I can find it in the nexus web,I declare this xxx-thrid as my parent project of myProject.

Howerver, I still have the maven error complaining that Cound not find artifact com.myCom:xxx-third:pom:2.0-SNAPSHOT @ com.myCom:myProject.

But if I do install locally with the code, the problem will resolve, this is annoying! Why and how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

It is because this artifact is in your local `.m2` repository on your local machine, but can't be downloaded from remote respository by your build server.
The local repostiory is in path:

```
{USER_HOME}\.m2\repository\
```

You can copy the required dependency from your local repository to the local repository on your build server, then it will read the jar dependecy from local repo instead of fetching it from remote repo.

Comment: ??Why? I have deploy it to the remote server and I can search it in the remote server already

Comment: what do you exactly mean by "why", have you any progress? Is this file on your build server?

Comment: I have deploy it to my remote repo, so I should be able to dowload it from the repo, but I can't. Copy for sure works but it is just a work around.

Comment: If you have properly published this artifact in your remote repo then it should be accessible. If you can't download it then there is some error in the settings of that dependency, check all the details of this artifact and compare them with what you have in your pom.

Answer (score 0):

Your parent POM is not resolved. There are three options to solve this:

1) Add the parent POM to your local repository

2) Add a relativePath to your child POM pointing to your parent POM (only makes sense in a multi-module project where source is in the same repository)

```
<parent>
    <groupId>...</groupId>
    <artifactId>...</artifactId>
    <version>...</version>
    <relativePath>...</relativePath>
</parent>
```

3) Add a repository configuration to your settings.xml (e.g. makes sense if you have a company wide POM)

```
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
  ...
  <profiles>
    <profile>
      ...
      <repositories>
        ...
      </repositories>
      ...
    </profile>
  </profiles>
  ...
```

As far as I understand 3) is your solution. See also:
https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html
https://maven.apache.org/settings.html